# Add string in Firebird 1.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Here what I'm trying to do..

Table name: `Message_Actions`
column: `Forward_details`

In Forward_detail column, I have strings values like:

```
EIioT
TIoH
EI
```

and so on..

I want to simply add the letter `G` at the end of each string without altering the existing

tried:

```
update Message_actions
set forward_details = forward_details || 'G' ;
```

no luck
but

```
update Message_actions
set forward_details = 'forward_details' || 'G' ;
```

results in `forward_detailsG`

Comment: What is the result of your first attempt?

Comment: What error do you get for your first attempt?

Comment: "no luck" is not a valid error message in Firebird (or any other DBMS)

Comment: Alex the first attempt overwrote the string : ie EIioT into forwarddetailsG

Comment: Hi Mark... trunc(forward_details) || 'G' gives me an error - ICS Error message: Dynamic SQL Error SQL Error code = -104 token unknown - line3, char 1 trunc..   this is what I wrote:                                       update message_actions
set forward_details
trunc(forward_details) || 'G'

Comment: @LeoFazzi The first attempt as above should work.  The second one would over-write the way you have said the first one did.  May I suggest you are confused about the results.  Please run the first one again and tell us what you get.  I would also like to know what dialect you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `trunc(forward_details) || 'G'`

Comment: You probably mean [`TRIM`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-trim.html)